# What characters are valid to use in filenames?

Tags: files, filesystems, filenames, namespace

I seems like it is possible to create filenames in unix with just about any valid character.

```
touch \; &&
touch \\ &&
touch \" &&
touch $'\n' &&
touch $'\t' &&
touch $'\v' &&
touch $'\23' &&
touch $'\13' &&
echo "DONE!"
```

The only characters I have found that does not work are `/` and `NUL`:

```
touch /
touch $'\0'
```

Are there any other characters that are invalid or impossible to use in filenames?

Comment: Related: [Understanding Unix file name encoding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39175/12779)

Comment: Only 0x00 and 0x2f are not allowed, everything else can be used from the kernel's perspective. That doesn't mean that all applications or file systems can deal with “funny” characters.

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155860/117549

Comment: At VFS level, only Nul is a forbidden character. A NFSclient may create a pathname component that contrains a /. Future POSIX versions may forbid characters 0x00..0x1F.

Comment: The question doesn’t say a single word about **Linux**, but high-rep users closed it as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi the linked *question* specifies Linux, but the answers to it aren’t Linux-specific.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer is: In Unix-like systems, file names are composed of **bytes**, not characters. At least from the perspective of the kernel and its APIs.

A Unix-like kernel is normally neutral about any byte value but `\000` (ASCII: NUL) and `\057` (ASCII: slash). In Linux, there are no other restrictions at the filesystem layer, but certain FS drivers and their modes lead to the rejection of some names, usually due to the impossibility of translation. For example, one can’t create a filename with invalid `UTF-8` on anything mounted with `-o iocharset=utf8` (e. g. types `cifs` or `vfat`). None of DOS/Windows-compatible FSes will allow you to make \134 (ASCII: backslash) a part of a name. Or the `msdos` type will apply DOS restrictions concerning 8.3 names.

Ext3/ext4 isn’t known to have restrictions but aforementioned `\000` and `\057`.

Comment: also, a filename has to contain at least one character.

Comment: There's also the fact that case-insensitive filesystems, like `msdos` and its ilk, will have problems with any filenames matching already existing files with different case, when there would otherwise be no conflict. Not exactly a character-based restriction, but is a consequence of character-based rules.