# Reference part of command in file that command creates

Tags: linux, bash

I’m using nmap for network reporting with something like the below example:

```
nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -oG filename_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y-%T').txt
```

How do I add the network scanned into the name of the file created? So for example, the file created looks like **192.168.1.0/24_07-01-2022.txt**

Thanks!

Comment: `/` is one of only two characters that cannot appear in a file name. `\0` is the other. You cannot create the file as hoped for. You can run `NET=192.168.1.0 nmap ${NET}/24 -oG f${NET}_$(date %d-%m-%Y-%T).txt`

Comment: Strictly speaking, you _can_ create the file as shown, but that would be one file and one directory: `192.168.1.0` would be a directory and `24_07-01-2022.txt` a file in that directory. I suspect that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out by @doneal24, `/` is one of the characters that cannot appear in a **filename** in an unix filesystems. See [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155793/is-it-correct-to-use-certain-special-characters-when-naming-filenames-in-linux).

You can use variable substitution for swapping `/` with `_` (or with any other character you like except `/` and `\000 (null character)`):

```
net=192.168.1.0/24 && nmap "$net" -oG "${net/\//_}_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y-%T')"
```

Later when you need to pick back the networks scanned just replace the `_` (or anything else) with `/` to get the network + netmask.

Comment: Also note that `nmap "$net" -oG "${net/\//_}_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y-%T')"` wouldn't work on systems where option processing is done the standard way (or if `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment on GNU systems at least). More generally you want to have options before non-option arguments. So `nmap -oG "${net/\//_}_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y-%T')" -- "$net"` here.

Comment: Yep @StéphaneChazelas but i have reused the code given in the OP