# How do I use null bytes in Bash?

Tags: bash, null

I've read that, since file-paths in Bash can contain any character except the null byte (zero-valued byte, `$'\0'`), that it's best to use the null byte as a separator. For example, if the output of `find` will be sent to another program, it's recommended to use the `-print0` option (for versions of `find` that have it).

But although something like this works fine (printing file-paths separated by newlines — don't worry, this is just a demonstration, I'm not actually doing it in real scripts):

```
find -print0 \
  | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' ; do echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

something like this does *not* work:

```
for file in * ; do echo -n "$file"$'\0' ; done \
  | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' ; do echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

When I try just the `for`-loop part, I find that it just prints all the filenames together, *without* the null byte in between.

Why is this? What's going on?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Bash uses C-style strings internally, which are terminated by null bytes. This means that a Bash string (such as the value of a variable, or an argument to a command) can never actually contain a null byte. For example, this mini-script:

```
foobar=$'foo\0bar'    # foobar='foo' + null byte + 'bar'
echo "${#foobar}"     # print length of $foobar
```

actually prints `3`, because `$foobar` is actually just `'foo'`: the `bar` comes after the end of the string.

Similarly, `echo $'foo\0bar'` just prints `foo`, because `echo` doesn't know about the `\0bar` part.

As you can see, the `\0` sequence is actually very misleading in a `$'...'`-style string; it looks like a null byte inside the string, but it doesn't end up working that way. In your first example, your `read` command has `-d $'\0'`. This works, but only because `-d ''` also works! (That's not an explicitly documented feature of `read`, but I suppose it works for the same reason: `''` is the empty string, so its terminating null byte comes immediately. `-d delim` is documented as using "The first character of *delim*", and I guess that even works if the "first character" is past the end of the string!)

But as you know from your `find` example, it *is* possible for a command to print out a null byte, and for that byte to be piped to another command that reads it as input. No part of that relies on storing a null byte *in a string inside Bash*. The only problem with your second example is that we can't use `$'\0'` in an argument to a command; `echo "$file"$'\0'` could happily print the null byte at the end, if only it knew that you wanted it to.

So instead of using `echo`, you can use `printf`, which supports the same sorts of escape sequences as `$'...'`-style strings. That way, you can print a null byte without having to have a null byte inside a string. That would look like this:

```
for file in * ; do printf '%s\0' "$file" ; done \
  | while IFS= read -r -d '' ; do echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

or simply this:

```
printf '%s\0' * \
  | while IFS= read -r -d '' ; do echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

(Note: `echo` actually also has an `-e` flag that would let it process `\0` and print a null byte; but then it would also try to process any special sequences in your filename. So the `printf` approach is more robust.)

---

Incidentally, there are some shells that *do* allow null bytes inside strings. Your example works fine in Zsh, for example (assuming default settings). However, regardless of your shell, Unix-like operating systems don't provide a way to include null bytes inside arguments to programs (since program arguments are passed as C-style strings), so there will always be some limitations. (Your example can work in Zsh only because `echo` is a shell builtin, so Zsh can invoke it without relying on the OS support for invoking other programs. If you used `command echo` instead of `echo`, so that it bypassed the builtin and used the standalone `echo` program on the `$PATH`, you'd see the same behavior in Zsh as in Bash.)

Comment: Why is IFS set to nothing if `-d ''` already means to delimit on `\0`? I found an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/bash-for-in-looping-on-null-delimited-string-variable#comment33868451_8677566

Comment: Bash CAN handle NULL bytes though. `echo -e "aaa\x00bbb"` does print the `bbb` part too. You just can’t assign it to variables, unless you escape them (e.g. `esc0() { sed 's/\xFF/\xFF\xFF/g; s/\x00/\xFF0/g'; }`)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: Yes; this answer mentions that. :-)