# Pipes vs variable assignment

Tags: pipe, variable

In what ways are pipes different from variable assignments?

I know you [can't use null bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174016/how-do-i-use-null-bytes-in-bash).  What other examples are there?

What about for piping in something like the following `yes | cat`?
I notice it outputs the `y` while assigning

```
test=`yes`
```

doesn't output anything.  Is the entire command executed before it pipes the data while `cat` is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test=`yes`
```

will attempt to read the complete output of `yes` and assign that to the variable `test`.

Since the output of `yes` is infinite, this assignment will invoke an infinite loop.

Under the hood, it uses the `pipe` operating system mechanism, just like the `|` operation does.

```
test=`yes`
```

is kind of like

```
yes | thisShell.slurpInputAndSaveToVariable test
```

`cat` doesn't try to slurp its whole input, which makes it possible for `yes` and `cat` to run concurrently as a streaming producer (and infinite one in this case) and consumer pair.

Comment: What is an example where of a piping command that runs infinitely completes something?

Comment: `yes |head -3` . `head` will only read 3 lines and then close. Upon closing its stdin (the output end of the pipe) the next write to the other end will cause the OS to kill the writing process with SIGPIPE, ending the infinite loop very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Piping

`yes` is a command that repeatedly outputs a string (defaults to "y") until killed. See `man yes`

`cat` is a command that outputs to STDOUT everything it receives on STDIN or the concatenation of all the files listed as parameters. See `man cat`

The pipe (`|`) redirects the STDOUT from the previous command to the STDIN of the next command.

Therefore, piping to `cat` is a waste of CPU cycles.

#### Variable assignment

Variable assignment allows you to temporarily store a string in memory.

Example:

```
$ test="this is a string!"
$ echo $test
this is a string!
```

If you want to store the result of a command in a variable, you would need to use a subshell.

Example:

```
$ echo "file contents :)" > test.file
$ test="$(cat test.file)"
$ echo $test
file contents :)
```

#### Reference

For detailed usage of bash, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines are very much what their name suggests: they offer a way to
stream data from one pipeline member to the next. Handling streams of
unbounded size is possible. Cases where processing an endless stream
make sense include those where progress or statistics about the
contents seen so far are printed from time to time, and where the user
can kill the pipeline whenever they want.

On the other hand, the shell substitution construct (backquotes or
`$()`) will not complete until the enclosed statement
terminates. Since the statement in your example, `yes`, does not
terminate, neither does `$(yes)`.

I would say that's one way in which assignment and piping differ
tremendously; one can't really assign a value of infinite length to a
variable, but piping one is fine and works.

Comment: So what if the command never completes will the data even be sent to the next command `cat`?  Is that why `yes | echo ` does nothing?

Comment: Piping data from a command that doesn't terminate is OK, whether it sends a finite or, as in the case of `yes`, infinite amount of data. In the case of `yes | echo`, the pipeline terminates because the command `echo` does not read its input: it simply exits after printing a single newline. The writing process, `yes`, will then receive a SIGPIPE signal as it tries to write, and will exit.