# What are the allowed values for a Bash variable?

Tags: bash, variable

I thought that a a Bash variable (of size 1) can hold any byte from 0 to 255. So any bitstream (in particular files) can fit in a Bash variable. But according to a comment I received, it cannot hold some bytes such as 0. So what are the allowed values (except for alphanumeric characters of course )?

Comment: Related: [How do I use null bytes in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174016/how-do-i-use-null-bytes-in-bash)